# 3D model with Placemark functionality

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-api

I am developing an interactive map using Google API and Sketchup. I have created and placed the 3D object using the following code:

```
var loc = ge.createLocation('');
loc.setLatitude(lookAt.getLatitude());
loc.setLongitude(lookAt.getLongitude());
model.setLocation(loc);

// set up the model's link (must be a COLLADA file).
// this model was created in SketchUp
var link = ge.createLink('');
model.setLink(link);
link.setHref('http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/' +
             'examples/static/splotchy_box.dae');

// create the model placemark and add it to Earth
var modelPlacemark = ge.createPlacemark('');
modelPlacemark.setGeometry(model);
ge.getFeatures().appendChild(modelPlacemark);

// zoom in on the model
lookAt.setRange(300);
lookAt.setTilt(80);
ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);

// persist the placemark for other interactive samples
window.placemark = modelPlacemark;
```

From this samples website: http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/interactive/index.html

I am trying to add into the 3D model the options of a regular Placemark (so it changes size when mouse hovers & is clickable).

I'm relatively new to the Google API so I was wondering: how can I add these functions to the 3D object?

I know how to create a regular placemark (from the same website), but I don't get how to make the 3D model a placemark.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

var placemark is a global variable, this is creating a 3D model in place of a placemark.
Try this code, its working for me.
I've used Google Earth plugin here.

```
    function createPlacemark() {
        console.log("in create placemark");
        placemark = ge.createPlacemark('');
        placemark.setName('placemark ' + counter);

        var model = ge.createModel('');
        ge.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark);
        var loc = ge.createLocation('');
        model.setLocation(loc);
        var link = ge.createLink('');

        // A textured model created in Sketchup and exported as Collada.
        link.setHref('https://sites.google.com/site/siddharthuit/downloads/crane.dae');
        model.setLink(link);


        var la = ge.getView().copyAsLookAt(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);

        // set location
        loc.setLatitude(la.getLatitude());
        loc.setLongitude(la.getLongitude());

        placemark.setGeometry(model);

        la.setRange(300);
        la.setTilt(45);
        ge.getView().setAbstractView(la);

    }
```

I've an another problem, do you know how to move a placemark according to the coordinates given dynamically from database

Comment: the building (3d object) appears, but doesn't do anything... what I am trying to accomplish is that it's a clickable object and that something (like an HTML balloon) will appear on top of it when you click it.

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply but you can do that if u add a invisible placemarker above it, if you need the code, i can help you with that.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the delayed reply and I apologize for my delay as well... if you could help me with the code I'd appreciate it indeed.